# Finding the minimum value in an array with MIPS

Tags: arrays, sum, mips, minimum

I'm trying to find the minimum value and the sum of an array in `MIPS`. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong that it gives out the wrong sum and it doesn't even seem to analyse and return the minimum value of the array.

I am only allowed to use two branch instructions, `bne` and `beq` but any other instruction is fair game.

```
# local variable    register
#   int sum     $s0
#   int min     $s1  (To be used when students enhance the program.)
#   int *p      $s2
#   int *past_last  $s3
#   
    .text
    .globl  main
main:
    la  $s2, arr        # p = arr
    addi    $s3, $s2, 24        # past_last = p + 6
    lw  $s0, ($s2)      # sum = *p
while:
    addi    $s2, $s2, 4     # p++
    beq $s2, $s3, endwhile  # if (p == past_last) goto L2
    lw  $t0, ($s2)      # $t0 = *p
    lw  $t1, -4($s2)        # $t1 = *(p--)
    slt $t2, $t1, $t0       # $t2 = 1 if (*p < *(p--)) else $t2 = 0
    bne $t2, $zero, minimum # if ($t2 != 0) goto minimum
    add $s0, $s0, $t0       # sum += $t0
    j   while
minimum:
    lw  $s1, ($t1)      # min = $t1
    j   while
endwhile:
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you move one register to another:

```
lw  $s1, ($t1)      # min = $t1
```

That instruction would read a word from the *address* contained in `$t1` and put it in `$s1`. The correct way to move a register to another would be:

```
move $s1, $t1
```

Or, if you don't want to use pseudo-instructions:

```
or $s1, $zero, $t1
```

---

Your method of calculating the minimum is flawed, since you only consider whether the element at position N is less than the element at position N-1. What you should do is initialize min (`$s1`) to the first element in the array before the loop (like you do with the sum), and then compare that against the current element for each iteration of the loop.

---

The `add, $s0, $s0, $t0` instruction should be placed *before* the `bne $t2, $zero, $minimum` instruction. Otherwise the current element won't be added to the sum when the branch is taken (unless your simulator/emulator emulates branch delay slots and your assembler doesn't automatically fill the delay slots for you).